# Gray Area On Google Map Canvas with error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'position' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

Am getting a very weird problem working with google maps;
When I initialize the map, I get a gray area in the map canvas and an error message

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'position' of undefined

Here is my code

```js
$(window).on("load", function () {

    var c = 'jumbo-map';

    function respondCanvas(canvas) {
        $(canvas).attr('width', $(canvas).parent().width());
        $(canvas).attr('height', $(canvas).parent().prev().height());
        initialize_map(canvas);
    }

    function initialize_map(canvas) {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(canvas, {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(2.778304, 32.301328),
            streetViewControl: false,
            mapTypeControl: true,
            panControl: true,
            zoomControl: true,
            zoom: 17
        });
    }

    respondCanvas(document.getElementById(c));

});
```

I've already seen these without any luck:

- [Google maps request returning "Cannot set property 'position' of undefined"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10499412/google-maps-request-returning-cannot-set-property-position-of-undefined)
- [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'position' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8483023/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-set-property-position-of-undefined)
- [Grey area in Google maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13901520/grey-area-in-google-maps)

Any help would be appreciated, thx in advance

Comment: You have a typo `var map = new google.maps.Map(c, {`, should be `var map = new google.maps.Map(canvas, {`

Comment: What geocodezip says, plus ... `$(window).resize(respondCanvas)` will call `respondCanvas` with a jQuery event as its argument, not the canvas element.

Comment: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7d9ttatq/1/)

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, sorry about the typos... the error is gone but am still getting gray canvas... even tried copying and pasting @geocodezip's [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7d9ttatq/1/) directly

Comment: i've managed to reproduce it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7d9ttatq/2/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem (which was not apparent from the JavaScript code in the question but could be seen in your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7d9ttatq/2/)) is that you are using a `<canvas>` element for the map.

Don't be misled by the use of the word `canvas` in any Maps API example code you may have looked at. Some Maps API examples use `canvas` for an element ID and/or variable name. This is a very poor choice of words in these examples! It's just an arbitrary name and doesn't imply that the element itself should use a `<canvas>` tag.

Change the `<canvas>` tag in your HTML code to a `<div>` and it will work.